# Переписать с select в ссылочную версию

Tags: html, select, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Хотел бы узнать, можно ли переписать такой код на ссылочную версию. То есть чтобы можно было выбрать порядок выбора не через select, а через ссылку.

```
        <div class="com-order-block">
            <label class="com-order-wrap">
                <span class="com-order-title">Порядок вывода комментариев:</span>
                <select class="com-order-select">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">По умолчанию</option>
                    <option value="desc" >Сначала новые</option>
                    <option value="asc" >Сначала старые</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.com-order-select').change(function() {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    var oldValue = ( /hesportscomOrder=(asc|desc)/.exec(document.cookie) || {} )[1] || '';
                    var newValue = elem.val();
                    console.log(oldValue, newValue);
                    if( newValue == oldValue ) {
                        return;
                    };
                    document.cookie = 'hesportscomOrder=' + encodeURIComponent(newValue) + '; path=/; expires=' + (new Date((new Date).getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*365)).toGMTString();
                    window.console && console.info && console.info('comment order changed: "' + oldValue + '" >> "' + newValue + '"');
                    // elem.parents('.com-order-wrap').eq(0).find('.com-order-apply').fadeIn().removeClass('com-order-apply-hidden').addClass('com-order-apply-visible');
                    newValue = newValue || 'default';
                    location.search = location.search
                        ? /[?&]comments_order=([^&]*)/.test(location.search)
                            ? location.search.replace(/comments_order=([^&]*)/, 'comments_order=' + newValue)
                            : location.search + '&comments_order=' + newValue
                        : '?comments_order=' + newValue;
                });
            }, 100);
        </script>
```

После изменения html часть должна выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
<div class="com-order-title2">Порядок вывода комментариев: <a href="javascript:void()" class="desc">сначала новые</a> <a href="javascript:void()" class="asc">сначала старые</a></div>
```

Если это достаточно трудоёмкая работа, то не могли бы вы описать порядок работы js скрипта, тогда сам попробую разобраться. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery у вас есть, судя по JS-коду, значит добавляем дата атрибуты к нажимаемым элементам:

```
<div class="com-order-title2">Порядок вывода комментариев:
     <span class="desc order-select" data-id="desc">сначала новые</span>
     <span class="asc order-select" data-id="asc">сначала старые</span>
</div>
```

Дальше правим скрипт, исходя из замены html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.order-select').click(function() {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    var oldValue = ( /hesportscomOrder=(asc|desc)/.exec(document.cookie) || {} )[1] || '';
                    var newValue = elem.attr("data-id");
                    console.log(oldValue, newValue);
                    if( newValue == oldValue ) {
                        return;
                    };
                    document.cookie = 'hesportscomOrder=' + encodeURIComponent(newValue) + '; path=/; expires=' + (new Date((new Date).getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*365)).toGMTString();
                    window.console && console.info && console.info('comment order changed: "' + oldValue + '" >> "' + newValue + '"');
                    // elem.parents('.com-order-wrap').eq(0).find('.com-order-apply').fadeIn().removeClass('com-order-apply-hidden').addClass('com-order-apply-visible');
                    newValue = newValue || 'default';
                    location.search = location.search
                        ? /[?&]comments_order=([^&]*)/.test(location.search)
                            ? location.search.replace(/comments_order=([^&]*)/, 'comments_order=' + newValue)
                            : location.search + '&comments_order=' + newValue
                        : '?comments_order=' + newValue;
                });
         });
</script>
```

В общем, скрипт не очень изменился, только до момента получения desc или asc на обработку, а ещё для `span` можно в css задать `cursor:poiner;`, чтобы выглядело как ссылка.

Comment: Лучший! Спасибо Вам! Даже не знаю, как вас отблагодарить. :)